# Getting wrong CREATED change from Firestore addSnapshotListener

Tags: ios, swift4, google-cloud-firestore

I have been using firestore in iOS Swift 4 for last few weeks to build a simple demo app as alternative to realm. It has a simple table view that gets populated and kept in sync across devices as user does CRUD operations

In my app - I have added a snapshotlistener to a query

```
self.changeListener = query.addSnapshotListener { [weak self](queryResultSnapshot, error) in
    //process document changes
}
```

In the callback - I have handled the added, updated, deleted changes based on DocumentChangeType present in queryResultSnapshot.changes.

Main problem is when I delete a document using

```
reference.delete(completion:)
```

After the delete is successful - I see the following events received in my querySnapshotListener.

```
//following is a debug message printed in delete function to correlate document ID
Will delete reference: i0W76CZP5X41vRp6BmzY     

//following 3 are printed in the snapshot change listener
Deleted reference: i0W76CZP5X41vRp6BmzY, Source of change: Server
Created reference: i0W76CZP5X41vRp6BmzY, Source of change: Server
Deleted reference: i0W76CZP5X41vRp6BmzY, Source of change: Server
```

In the above print - i'm using the pending writes flag to print the source of change also. As we can see - when i do a delete - I get a delete notification, immediately followed by a additional create / delete of same document reference.

Does anyone else see this behavior? I did not see this behavior till couple of days back - so I'm curious if there is something that i need to handle?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use db transaction for deleting and this problem will not occur. For example:

```
Firestore.firestore().runTransaction({(transaction, error) -> Any? in

    return transaction.deleteDocument(docReference)

}) { [weak self](object, err) in
    // do something when operation is done
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much @artembolotov. That did it

Comment: @artembototov - quick update, the use of transaction removed the ability to use the offline mode. So i had to remove it. The behavior i originally observed was definitely a firestore bug because it resolved itself a couple of weeks ago

Comment: @firestore-ram, great! In my project this problem also were resolved by itself but then were occurred again!